# how to make an accordion constructor function with pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

i am trying to make a constructor function for an accordion with pure javaScript but it dosen't work... i guess it has something to do with the "this" keyword misbehaving.. I have written the code with a normal function and it did work but it dosen't with the constructor below.

```js
function Accordion(accordionId) {
  this.container = document.getElementById(accordionId);
  this.headers = this.container.getElementsByClassName("accordion-header");
  this.sections = this.container.getElementsByClassName("accordion-section");
  for (var i = 0; i < this.headers.length; i++) {
    this.headers[i].addEventListener("click", this.toggleSections);

  }
  this.toggleSections = function() {
    var toggeld = this.nextElementSibling.className;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.sections.length; i++) {
      this.sections[i].className = "accordion-section";
    }
    if (toggeld === "accordion-section") {
      this.nextElementSibling.className = "accordion-section-displayed";
    } else {
      this.nextElementSibling.className = "accordion-section";
    }
  }
}
 var newAccordion = new Accordion("accordion-wrapper");
```

```html
<div id="accordion-wrapper">
  <h3 class="accordion-header">First Section</h3>
  <div class="accordion-section">
    .
  </div>
  <h3 class="accordion-header">Second Section</h3>
  <div class="accordion-section">

  </div>
  <h3 class="accordion-header">Third Section</h3>
  <div class="accordion-section">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: For one `this.sections` is not available to the click event

Comment: thank you for your reply. It was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few things wrong here.

1. You are setting the click handler to `this.toggleSections` before you define what `this.toggleSections` is. You should define it before setting the click handlers.
2. Your `this` context in the click handler will be the element that was clicked, not your Accordion instance. There are a few way around this. You can either set another variable, `self` to equal `this` outside of the click handler and change `this.sections` to `self.sections` in the click handler (and any other instance variables you need). My preferred method, however, is to `bind` this to your click handler instead:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
3. If you decided to go down the `bind` avenue, you will have to update your `this.nextElementSibling` references because the `this` context is no longer the clicked element. You can get the clicked element by adding an `event` paraemeter to your click handler and reference `event.target` instead of `this`.

Comment: i am really thankful for your comment. Yeah, i got  the feeling it had something to do with the this keyword since it refers to the event when put in the event handler. I tried making this equals self and it worked very well for me. The last point about the bind method open for me new things to learn so i guess i have to read about it more.. many thanks for your reply.. please if you have any advises for me  i will be glad :)

Comment: Fully understanding the `this` context takes time, trial, and failure, to really learn. ES6 syntax (if your use-case allows for it) adds a fat-arrow function which is more or less syntactic sugar to bind `this` on the enclosing function. Read the "Lexical this" section: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions

Comment: yeah, i have read about those arrow functions somewhere before. I will focus more on those stuffs, i guess they will add more functionality to my codes.. thank you again :)

Comment: would you please tell me how to make the other content divs disappear if i clicked on another header? i used a for loop in the beginning of the self.toggleSections methode but it makes no change.